# Detecting ABI compatibility issues with GCC

Tags: debugging, gcc, g++, glibc, abi

I recently spent a fairly substantial amount of time tracking down a problem that turned out to be caused by compiling a library with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` (which tells libstdc++ to use a debug version of the standard library with extra checks) but compiling the client program without. This caused an ABI compatibility problem.

Is there some way I can automatically detect problems like this with GCC? Visual Studio provides the [`detect_mismatch` pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956429.aspx) which I think would have served this purpose, but I'm unaware of any GCC equivalent. GCC does something with embedding a symbol name (e.g. `GLIBCXX_3.4.9`), and I can imagine schemes that would cause a linking error because of an undefined symbol if a corresponding symbol (e.g. `mylib_debug_stl`) were not present, but the only ways I can think of to get a *use* of that symbol are really hacky.

Alternatively, how do other people avoid this issue? Build the checked version of the library to a different name or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some way I can automatically detect problems like this with GCC?

Only the linker can detect if you link incompatible code, not the compiler.

The alternative linker, `gold`, can detect some problems with the `--detect-odr-violations` option.

> Alternatively, how do other people avoid this issue? Build the checked version of the library to a different name or something like that?

I just ensure I rebuild everything when I want to use the Debug Mode, I don't think I've ever wanted to keep a library around that was built with Debug Mode. It's meant for debugging, not for normal use.

I rarely use `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` anyway, I more often do something like:

```
#if 0
# include <debug/vector>
namespace my_class_stl = __gnu_debug;
#else
#include <vector>
namespace my_class_stl = std;
#endif

struct my_class
{
  typedef my_class_stl::vector<int> container;
  typedef container::iterator iterator;
  // ...
};
```

Then I change the preprocessor condition when I want to use a Debug Mode vector for that specific class, without affecting **every** container in the program.  Because the change involves writing to the file (and so updating its timestamp) anything that depends on that header will get rebuilt by `make`, and there are two distinct types, `std::vector<int>` and `__gnu_debug::vector<int>`, which have different symbols and can't be confused by the linker.

Just defining `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` doesn't cause all dependencies to be rebuilt, and silently alters the definition of `std::vector` globally, rather than changing specific containers to a different type with a different name, `__gnu_debug::vector`

Comment: I tried --detect-odr-violations (with Gold) and it was silent on my issue. I went back to [the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt03ch17s04.html#debug_mode.design.methods.coexistence), and from what I can tell, your suggestion to use namespace aliases is actually somewhat similar to what GNU's libstdc++ tries to do; they put the non-debug containers into std::__cxx1998, the release containers into std::__debug, and then use a namespace association ("inline namespace") to bring the appropriate one into scope in std. [continued]

Comment: [continued] My read of that is that it _should_ also be avoiding linker problems... which makes me wonder if there's a "bug" in the library that's causing it to not detect it in my case.

Comment: let's continue this on the libstdc++ list

Comment: @JonathanWakely It doesn't *silently* change the definition -- the mangled name changes, and you should get link errors (unresolved symbols) if you rebuild parts, but not all that requires rebuild.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, see the example I gave at http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-10/msg00077.html which _does_ get a silent change in meaning that doesn't affect any mangled symbols and doesn't cause linker errors, but causes runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

> turned out to be caused by compiling a library with -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG (which tells libstdc++ to use a debug version of the standard library with extra checks) but compiling the client program without.

It is an *explicit* `libsdc++` debugging mode design goal to support such configuration, and I somewhat doubt that that was the *actual* cause of your problem.

The problem may have disappeared after you rebuilt the library without `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, but that doesn't prove that the `ABI` incompatibility was the root cause.

Comment: (1) I had a program that was crashing on bad memory accesses when building when inconsistent _GLIBCXX_DEBUG settings and yet not only failed to crash but valgrinded clean when compiled with consistent settings in either direction. (2) It is an explicit **goal** of the `libstdc++` mode to detect such errors, but as Jonathan Wakely linked above (http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-10/msg00077.html), they did not achieve this goal in full. (And from my understanding will be unable to without explicit support from the GCC C++ compiler and linker.)